# Optimize ByteArray copy

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, optimization, arrays

Below is a code snippet from flashlight-VNC library, which decompresses (using ByteArray.inflate) the incoming byte stream.

```
package com.flashlight.zlib
{

    import com.flashlight.utils.TimeTracker;

    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import mx.logging.ILogger;
    import mx.logging.Log;

    public class Inflater {
        private var lastDeflate:ByteArray;

        public function uncompress(compressedData:ByteArray):ByteArray {
            var uncompressedData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var dataOffset:int = lastDeflate ? 0 : 2;

            TimeTracker.startTimer("TightEncoding[CopyCompresion]");
            if (lastDeflate) {
                var dictionarySize:int = lastDeflate.length > 32768 ? 32768 : lastDeflate.length;
                uncompressedData.writeByte(0x00);
                uncompressedData.writeByte(dictionarySize );
                uncompressedData.writeByte(dictionarySize >> 8);
                uncompressedData.writeByte(~dictionarySize);
                uncompressedData.writeByte((~dictionarySize) >> 8 );
                uncompressedData.writeBytes(lastDeflate,lastDeflate.length - dictionarySize, dictionarySize);
            }
            uncompressedData.writeBytes(compressedData,dataOffset,compressedData.length-dataOffset);
            TimeTracker.stopTimer("TightEncoding[CopyCompresion]");
            uncompressedData.writeByte(0x01);
            uncompressedData.writeUnsignedInt(0x0000FFFF);

            TimeTracker.startTimer("TightEncoding[Realdecompress]");
            uncompressedData.inflate(); 
            TimeTracker.stopTimer("TightEncoding[Realdecompress]");

            lastDeflate = uncompressedData;
            uncompressedData.position = dictionarySize;

            return uncompressedData;
        }

    }
}
```

There is a constant stream of compressed data coming from the server, which is inflated block by block by the Inflater class. inflate() and writeBytes() methods together take 99% of the time in this class. inflate() is already a native call.

How can writeBytes call be optimized? Can we skip it, rewiring this code some other way or is there better optimized way to do ByteArray copy thing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if ByteArray can be optimized, as long as it is a native Flash class. I guess you could try some third-party libraries/frameworks such as Fluorine or Alchemy to call C++ algorithm that could be faster.

Comment: I tried that, for a cpu extensive "for" loop but passing bytearray across takes good amount of time :(

Comment: I am looking into haxe/azoth right now to boost up ByteArray performance.